# difference between webclient downloaded webpage and browser displayed page

Tags: vb.net

im trying to download this web page in vb.net:

http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=35425587644337450&c=27

with these source codes:

```
Using client As New WebClient
        Dim arr() As Byte = client.DownloadData("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=35425587644337450&c=27")
        MessageBox.Show(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr))
    End Using
```

and

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=35425587644337450&c=27")
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            File.WriteAllText("test.html", html)
        End Using
    End Using
```

but result is:

```
S�,��e5#;�W�I����^#�+���OO�l�@����5���|�`G��
```

whats problem?
thanks

Comment: I can't see the webpage, but are you sure it's in UTF8?

Comment: @the_lotus   yes. save it in UTF8 and ascii . not Working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`File.WriteAllText("test.html", html)`

use

`File.WriteAllBytes("test.html", html)`

**Update:**

The response from the web serve is GZipped.  You'll need to decompress the text.  Try something like the following....

```
Dim wreq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=35425587644337450&c=27")
wreq.AutomaticDecompression = Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip

Dim wres As System.Net.WebResponse = wreq.GetResponse
Dim s As System.IO.Stream = wres.GetResponseStream
Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(s)
Dim html As String = sr.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: html is string no byte array!

Comment: @user4348709 I have updated the answer with additional code to deal with the GZip data being returned.  You should be able to convert this to meet your needs

Comment: The content is GZipped. You edited the question, I've removed the downvote